# Set default date of uploaded files

Tags: 2007, default-value

In SharePoint 2007 whenever I go to initially check in an uploaded file, I have to enter the date.
1) Is there a way that I or the SharePoint admin can make this default to the file date?
2) If not, can I make it the current date and time?
3) Or at least the current date (it seems to default the time to midnight)?

The specific field is Date Modified and this field is shown at check in time.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by you have to enter the date?  Is this a required field in your content type?

Comment: All SharePoint lists, even Document Libraries, include both a 'Created' and 'Modified' fields that are populated with the appropriate datetime automatically.

Comment: It sounds like there's another column attached to the library or content type that's asking for a date.  I'm sure that it can be changed to use a default value or a calculated value.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your DateTime field's default value by:

1. Navigate to your list
2. Click Settings -> Document Library Settings
3. Click your column's name, ex: "Date Modified"
4. Set the "Default value" radio button to "Today's Date"

I'd be interested in your actual requirements because, as @Dave Wise mentions, there are already columns called Created and Modified that track these dates.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know if that works.